# How to drop a div between two divs using plain JavaScript (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I use the below code to drag items (left) to the drop items (right). Once dragged to the right, they can be dragged back to the left.

I'm using

```
document.getElementById(dropID).appendChild(document.getElementById(dragID))
```

to drag them back, so they always are added as the last div.

Is there any way to drag the item to the left, positioned between other divs that are already in the left? instead of always added to the end?

Also this would allow to sort the items in the left by just dragging them between them, is this easy without using jquery? thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.dragAndDropContainer {
  display: flex ;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif ; 
}

.dragItems {
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}  

.dragItem {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: rgb(52,118,177);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dragItem:hover {
  background: rgb(117, 168, 255);
}

.dropItems {
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
} 

 .dropItem {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(160, 160, 160);
  background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropItem:hover {
  color: white;
  background: rgb(73, 86, 92);
}

</style>
<script>

  // source based on: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

function allowDrop(ev) {
  var dropID =  ev.currentTarget.id;
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("dragEventID", ev.currentTarget.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var dragID = ev.dataTransfer.getData("dragEventID");
  var dropID =  ev.currentTarget.id;
  var dropClass =  ev.currentTarget.getAttribute("class");
  var maximumDragItemsPerDropArea = 1 ;

  if (dropClass=="dragItems") {
    document.getElementById(dropID).appendChild(document.getElementById(dragID));
  }  
  else if (dropClass = "dropItems") {
    if (document.getElementById(dropID).childElementCount < maximumDragItemsPerDropArea) {
      document.getElementById(dropID).appendChild(document.getElementById(dragID));
    } else {
      console.log("maximum "+ maximumDragItemsPerDropArea) ;
      console.log(document.getElementById(dropID).children) ;
      // alert("max");
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dragAndDropContainer" class="dragAndDropContainer">

<div id="dragItems" class="dragItems" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div id="dmDragItemID1" class="dragItem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" > Drag item 1 </div>
<div id="dmDragItemID2" class="dragItem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" > Drag item 2 </div>
<div id="dmDragItemID3" class="dragItem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" > Drag item 3 </div>
</div>

<div id="dropItems" class="dropItems">
  <div id="dmDropItemID1" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop item 1</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID2" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop item 2</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID3" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop item 3</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID4" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop item 4</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I got it working, thanks to this link:

https://codepen.io/fitri/pen/VbrZQm

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.dragAndDropContainer {
  display: flex ;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif ; 
  font-size: 11px;
}

.dragItems {
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid rgb(160, 160, 160);
}  

.dragItem {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: rgb(52,118,177);
  color: white;
}

.dragItem:hover {
  background: rgb(117, 168, 255);
}

.dropItems {
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
} 

 .dropItem {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropItem:hover {
  color: white;
  background: rgb(73, 86, 92);
}

</style>
<script>
/* 

Resources:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
https://codepen.io/fitri/pen/VbrZQm

*/

function allowDrop(ev) {
  var dropID =  ev.currentTarget.id;
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("dragEventID", ev.currentTarget.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var dragID = ev.dataTransfer.getData("dragEventID");
  var dropID =  ev.currentTarget.id;
  var dropClass =  ev.currentTarget.getAttribute("class");
  var maximumDragItemsPerDropArea = 1 ;

if (dropClass == "dragItems") {

    elementDropPoint = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    // If drop area is the drag items container div, we add the dragged div to the end
    if (elementDropPoint.className == "dragItems") {
        document.getElementById(dropID).appendChild(document.getElementById(dragID));
    }
    // If drop area is between two drag item divs, we add the dragged div in the drop area, after the existing drag div
    if (elementDropPoint.className == "dragItem") {
      elementDropPoint.after(document.getElementById(dragID));
    }
  }

  if (dropClass == "dropItem") {
    if (document.getElementById(dropID).childElementCount < maximumDragItemsPerDropArea) {
      document.getElementById(dropID).appendChild(document.getElementById(dragID));
    } else {
      console.log("maximum "+ maximumDragItemsPerDropArea) ;
      console.log(document.getElementById(dropID).children) ;
      // alert("max");
    }
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dragAndDropContainer" class="dragAndDropContainer">


<div id="dragItems" class="dragItems" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div id="dmDragItemID1" class="dragItem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" > FileNotes021.png </div>
<div id="dmDragItemID2" class="dragItem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" > FileNotes025.png </div>
<div id="dmDragItemID3" class="dragItem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" > FileNotes019.png </div>
<div id="dmDragItemID4" class="dragItem" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" > FileNotes015.png </div>
</div>

<div id="dropItems" class="dropItems">
  <div id="dmDropItemID1" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Song 1</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID2" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Song 2</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID3" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Song 3</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID4" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Song 4</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID5" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Song 5</div>
<div id="dmDropItemID6" class="dropItem" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Song 6</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ChildNode.before() method to insert your element right before any other target:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before

Also, this assignment you have in the condition check looks like it's a mistake:

`else if (dropClass = "dropItems") {`

Comment: Thanks! yes that was a mistake, I corrected it to be ```dropClass == "dropItem" ```